# AFNetworking post parameters not encoding

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, afnetworking-2

I'm getting an error using `AFNetworking 2.0` while using post method in Swift language because the body isn't encoded as it should be, here is my code:

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = true;

let reqSerializer: AFJSONRequestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
reqSerializer.setValue("T-Rex", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
reqSerializer.setValue("no-cache", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")
reqSerializer.setValue("apikey", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
manager.requestSerializer = reqSerializer

let resSerializer: AFJSONResponseSerializer =  AFJSONResponseSerializer()
resSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = ["text/html", "application/json"]
manager.responseSerializer = resSerializer;
let params: NSDictionary = ["userName" : userName, "passWord" : passWord]

manager.POST(Constants.apiURL.url + "users/login",
    parameters:params,
    success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        NSLog("Success! Response is \(responseObject.description)")
    },
    failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
        NSLog("Failure! Error is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
})
```

Debugging the request I get:

```
POST 'http://api.cc/users/login': {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "pt;q=1, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8";
    Authorization = apikey;
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    "User-Agent" = "T-Rex";
} {"passWord":"123","userName":"123"}
```

and my server answer:

```
400 'http://api.cc/users/login' [0.7545 s]: {
    Age = 0;
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 83;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sun, 06 Sep 2015 01:03:00 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.8.0";
    Via = "1.1 varnish-v4";
    "X-Varnish" = 950329;
} {"error":true,"message":"Required field(s) userName, passWord is missing or empty"}
```

I don't know why the username and password is encoded like this:

```
{"passWord":"123","userName":"123"}
```

instead of this:

```
{"passWord:123&userName":123"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` instead of `AFJSONRequestSerializer`.

Problem solved.